# loading osmfile in pyroutelib2

Tags: python, distance, openstreetmap

Hi im new in python programming,

currently im in a project which need to find distance between 2 points (lat&lon) offline.

I know google maps provide this service but i cant use it since it has a limit for free account.

So, im googling around and find pyroutelib2 can do this for me with using openstreetmap map data.

[pyroutelib link](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PyrouteLib)

and now im kinda stuck. im running on Windows 8 x64. my python is 2.7.
i have downloaded pyroutelib from this link 
http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/routing/pyroutelib2/

and have my country map (osm.bz2 file) ready. the problem is, while i type the command

```
loadosm.py f:\asia.osm car
loadosm.py f:\asia.osm.bz2 car
loadosm.py f:\asia.osm.pbf car
```

(the osm file is in different directory)

in my console, the osm file wont be loaded and returning this message:

```
Loaded 0 nodes
Loaded 0 cycle routes
Searching for node: found None
```

anybody please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I get the same output. Either pyroutelib2 or its documentation is broken.

I suggest to just use another routing library/tool. See the OSM wiki about [routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing#Developers) as well as the list of [online routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers) and [offline routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/offline_routers). There are lots of interesting solutions available.

Answer (score 0):

Check out **osmapi**, it's what I've used to get OSM files and import them into pyroutelib2. I don't know if that will solve your problems, but I've had luck going that route.